# Php split a string to to string

Tags: php, split

I want to split a variable that I call for $ NowPlaying which contains the results of the current song. I would now like to share the following - so I get two new variables containing $ artist 
 $ title. Having searched and tried to find a solution, but have stalled grateful for a little assistance, and help

Comment: Can you show an example of the variable? There are several different ways to split it, but it would depend on the delimiter.

Comment: What have you tried? Additionally, this question doesn't have enough information to be answered correctly. What is your input variable's type? String, array?

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
// Assuming $NowPlaying is something like "J. Cole - Chaining Day" 
// $array = explode("-", $NowPlaying); //enter a delimiter here, - is the example
$array = explode(" - ", $NowPlaying); //DJHell pointed out this is better
$artist = $array[0]; // J. Cole
$song = $array[1]; // Chaining Day
// Problems will arise if the delimiter is simply (-), if it is used in either 
// the song or artist name.. ie ("Jay-Z - 99 Problems") so I advise against 
// using - as the delimiter. You may be better off with :.: or some other string
?>
```

Comment: If you use " - " for exploding var, instead of "-", you don't have to trim the results and it's a bit more safe (ie: with "Jay-Z"). Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `php` **[explode()](https://www.php.net/explode)** function

```
$str_array = explode(' - ', $you_song);
// then you can get the variables you want from the array
$artist = $str_array[index_of_artist_in_array];
$title  = $str_array[index_of_title_in_array];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're wanting to use `explode()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

I would usually do some thing like this:

```
<?php    
$input = 'Your - String';
$separator = ' - ';
$first_part = substr($input, 0, strpos($input, $separator));
$second_part = substr($input, (strpos($input, $separator) + strlen($separator)), strlen($input));
?>
```

I have looked at a couple split string questions and no one suggests using the php string functions. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score -1):

list() is made for exactly this purpose.

```
<?php
  list($artist, $title) = explode(' - ', $NowPlaying);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: that's not correct. You use list with arrays not with strings.

Comment: No... list is made to do what it says in the link you posted.

Comment: Yeah - I shouldn't have skimmed the original question. Fixed it now.